# SharePoint 2013 User Profile Can't Sync with AD

Tags: 2013, active-directory, sync, service

I used to have SP13 sync with AD until I deleted the Service application, and now no matter what I do, the synchronization service won't start and I'm getting this error in event log:

> The Execute method of job definition
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.LMTRepopulationJob (ID
>   764bc1f8-4bb4-4779-bc20-58ed33297a31) threw an exception. More
>   information is included below.
>
> An update conflict has occurred, and you must re-try this action. The
>   object LMTRepopulationJob Name=User Profile Service_LMTRepopulationJob
>   was updated by ***NYDOMAIN***\spfarmservice, in the w3wp (13040)
>   process, on machine ***MYSERVERNAME***.  View the tracing log for more
>   information about the conflict

I've tried everything found on Google, including:
 - removing and reinstalling the service application
 - Clear the cach and reset IIS

I already configured mysites and I am able to connect to AD and select my containers

Comment: Are you using the same databases or new databases with the recreated UPA?

Comment: what are the permissions on the sync account? Does it have necessary permissions to the AD (Replicate Changes)?

Comment: @JesusShelby  - Thank you for replying, I deleted the old database, this is a new database

Comment: @Mike the sync account is in my admin group and btw something the profile sync service gets stuck on staring and after a few minutes stops

Comment: that is unrelated to the permissions that it needs to sync to the active directory: See here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh296982.aspx

Comment: @Mike is correct, It's almost always a permission issue.  Review Spence Harbars "stuck on starting" as well: http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups2.aspx  If those checks don't yield results then I think you will need to break out some combination of ProcMon, Fiddler, and SQL Profiler to find the root of the issue.

Comment: @Mike - thx, but I already did and double these steps and still having the same issue

Answer (score 2):

Thank you everybody for your contribution but I got it to work. This is what seemed to work for me and the steps involved after making sure I followed all the steps of:

Creating different accounts
Configuring Active directory and adding the proper accounts and such. Read the comments on from @Mike to see the links that would explain the steps.

Like @Mike and @JesusShelby mentioned, it was a permission issue. Here's what I did:

I removed the previous sync connection to AD under application Management> Manage Service application> User profile service> Configure Synchronization connection

Then,

I went to Application Management> Manage Service application> selected User Profile service  chose Administrators and added my UPS sync account as an admin. Before I only had my spservices account in there and not the ADsync account.

then,
 Went back to Application Management> Manage Services on Server and started the User Profile Synchronization Service  with the spservice account and *this time it didn't get stuck on starting!!*

then,

Went to the User profile service Application created a connection with AD with the adsync and did a full sync and that seemed to do the trick.